# Magento 2 - Error when uploading image

Tags: magento2, image-upload, design

I'm trying to change the logo of my Magento store so I go to Content > Design > Configuration, I click Edit on the Default Store View, I scroll down to Other Settings and open Header... I already have a logo there so I click on the trash icon to remove it, then I click on Upload and select the new logo I want from my computer. The logo loads properly, but when I click on Save Configuration, I get the following error message:

"Something is wrong with the file upload settings."

[image]

Also I remove the Favicon Icon and I was able to save the configurations with no error, but the icon still appears in the front end even though the Admin shows that there is no icon.

`Note: My Magento 2 version is 2.4.4`

Comment: Which version you have of Magento 2 ?

Comment: Magento 2 version 2.4.4

Comment: `/pub/media/logo/stores/` check for the proper permission

Answer (score 0):

You face this issue because your file is not allowed. Allowed extensions for **logo** files are **jpg, jpeg, gif, and png**.

Comment: my logo extension is png, so that's not the issue

Comment: Make sure your logo extension is lowercase. Eg: if the logo file is mylogo.PNG, magento will throw the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced the same. In my case it was because the file extension was UPPER CASE. Renaming .JPG to .jpg worked a treat for me at least.

I can't quite believe that was the simple answer, but worked in my case. Crazily poor error message if that was the reason!